# React not adding item to array properly Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write a basic query search for a Firestore database.

```
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const recipesCollectionRef = collection(db, "recipes");

  const onSearch = async (queryText) => {
    setRecipes([]);
    if (typeof queryText == "string" && queryText != ""){
      const q = query(recipesCollectionRef, where("name",">=",queryText), where("name","<=",queryText+"\uf8ff"))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      console.log("Search")
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setRecipes(recipes.concat([doc.data()]));
        console.log(doc.data())
      });
      console.log(recipes)
    }
  }
```

Running this command 3 times; typing "P", "Pi", "Piz" (into queryText); I get this in console:

```
 LOG  Search
 LOG  {"name": "Pizza", "temp": null, "time": 8}
 LOG  {"name": "Pizza", "temp": 4, "time": 11}
 LOG  []
 LOG  Search
 LOG  {"name": "Pizza", "temp": null, "time": 8}
 LOG  {"name": "Pizza", "temp": 4, "time": 11}
 LOG  [{"name": "Pizza", "temp": 4, "time": 11}]
 LOG  Search
 LOG  {"name": "Pizza", "temp": null, "time": 8}
 LOG  {"name": "Pizza", "temp": 4, "time": 11}
 LOG  [{"name": "Pizza", "temp": 4, "time": 11}, {"name": "Pizza", "temp": 4, "time": 11}]
```

Why does only the last entry "Pizza" get put into the array? Also, why does setRecipes([]) not reset the recipes array?

Comment: you should use `===` & `!==` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Firebase Firestore database is not designed for search-like queries. I advise using the Algolia Firebase extension - https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/algolia-firestore-algolia-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setRecipes` is an async function. The value `recipes` will be not updated until the next render.

Try calling setRecipes only once per render.

```
const temp = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        temp.push(doc.data());
      });
setRecipes(temp);
```

Then to view the state as is updates

```
useEffect(() => console.log(recipes), [recipes]);
```